# keytool - import error : Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: keystore

I am getting following error while generating certificates on my local machine.

```
D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin>keytool.exe -import -alias kish -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/lib/security/cacerts" -file D:/{my_server}/mycertificate.cer

Enter keystore password:

keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I might be missing something here.(note: password is correct)

Please share your inputs.

Comment: I'm getting this too all of a sudden. Keystore was not tampered with otherwise it would have shown up as a changed file in git. Password is also correct. Google is wrong !